# Invalid accelerator data region: branching into or out of region is not allowed?

Tags: openacc

pgcc is showing "Invalid accelerator data region: branching into or out of region is not allowed" for the lines that I put my acc pragmas, but I don't understand why.

I'm using copy, copyin, and create for all arrays that the loops would utilize.

What am  I missing? Thanks!

```
#pragma acc data copy(graph->pagerank), copyin(graph->indegree, graph->outdegree), create(pagerankNew) 
while (1) {
   #pragma acc kernels 
   { 
     for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < graph->indegree[i]; ++k) {
           //int j = graph->inlinks[i][k];
           int j = 0;
           sum += (1.0 / graph->outdegree[j]) * graph->pagerank[j];

        }
        pagerankNew[i] = firstterm + damping * sum;

        double diff = fabs(graph->pagerank[i] - pagerankNew[i]);
        // if(iterations > 50) {
        if (diff != 0.000000 && diff < epsilon) {
           return iterations;
        }
     }

     for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        graph->pagerank[k] = pagerankNew[k];
     }
  }

  ++iterations;
}
```

Comment: It's the `return` statement.  That is branching out of an accelerator region.  One possible approach would be to  change that `return` statement into something that exits the accelerator regions normally (i.e. drops out of the while loop normally), and then does the actual `return` outside of the regions scoped by your pragmas.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella, that got rid of that error. Would you happen to know how I get rid of a "loop carried dependence" warning? The bottom most for loop in my code is giving me that warning and it just copies the array over

Comment: try marking the pointers involved with the `restrict` keyword as described on slide 43 [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#streams)

Comment: You can also use the "independent" clause on a loop directive to assert to the compiler that the loop is independent.